# How can I count registers that created in last 24 hours?

Tags: php, mysql

Example MySQL;

```
username work date(TIMESTAMP)

x        1    2012-08-08 12:15:33
x        3    2012-10-08 12:11:33
x        4    2012-08-08 11:15:33
x        2    2012-07-08 12:15:33
```

I want to take controle with just one rule;

X can only make 3 work mysql registry in 24 hours.

I could not find the true MySQL command for that.
How can I controle that via MySQL and php?

Comment: Could you try rephrasing your question? It's difficult to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you count of more than 3

```
select username from table
where date>=dateadd(current_date+interval -1 day)
group by username  
having count(*)>3
```

Comment: @Slavez You need to alter the query to fit your database needs. The `table` table and the `date` field are just example, canonical answers.

Comment: It always giving error when I try, so I sent you my mysql table's image, maybe this can help. http://666kb.com/i/c69hhgneis16umdgh.png

Answer (score 1):

This will return how many jobs were set by user 'x' in the last day:

```
select count(*) as jobCount from yourTable where date>=date_sub(now(), 1 day) and userName='x'
```

You can check when placing a new job to see if the user is in the list and the jobCount is at least 3.

Comment: It's giving syntax error when I tried with my values like

select count(*) as jobCount from kupon where date>=date_sub(now(), 1 day) and isim='slavez'

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT username , COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM  table_name
WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 day),
GROUP BY username 
HAVING cnt <= 3;
```